# SharePoint Foundation 2010 List Workflow can't write to a file on a remote network host

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, permissions

I have created a list workflow in Visual Studio which writes XML to a file on a network drive.

I have confirmed that I can access the drive from the SharePoint host.  I can also manually create/modify/delete the file with my permissions.

When I try to execute the workflow from SharePoint (executed manually), I receive an exception stating that access is denied.

As I understand it, the SharePoint workflow should execute with the same credentials as the logged in user.

Is my understanding of the credentials used to execute the workflow correct?  Do I need to have any special permissions set up for SharePoint itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumptions above were correct.  The issue actually turned out to be network related (the workflow needed the FQDN of the target host for the export).

In my case, I was able to write the file to the network share (once the address for the remote host was corrected) without using [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivledges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) or any other special changes.